# NSPredicate for searching inside array property with array

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Need a `NSPredicate` or `NSCompoundPredicate` to filter using `NSFetchedResultsController` while searching.

I need To list the parents. Where **parent_name** or the parent who is containing in the **group_name** who has the search string. Since we cannot use block predicate for NSFetchedResultsController. Can anyone suggest me to achieve this.

**Note:**
*I don't have the relationship mapped to the group. I just only has the group_ids as an NSArray in Parent.*

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789

Comment: Can you explain your question  a bit more, in your "Parent", there are "group_ids" which are connected to "id" in Group, and you want to check if Parent "name" is same as Group "name"?

Comment: *Note: I don't have the relationship mapped to the group. I just only has the group_ids as an NSArray in Parent.* – You did it wrong and get problems with that, but do not want to correct this?

Comment: @Munahil, No I 'm listing the parents in tableview, where it shows the parent name and group name. If I search say "Asa" I have to list the parents whose (name contains Asa or the parent who is in the group name which contains Asa). Is that clear.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, No I did it for purpose. It will contains somewhat 2000+ records. I'm having the groups as separate and parents separate. So having Ids alone in the parents. Can you suggest me the right way of doing this.

Comment: I did not say that it is accidentally wrong. Build a relationship between them. I do not know, why this should be impossible with 2000+ records and do not believe it.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, thanks. I will build an relationship and let you know.